# Unable to run upgrade on Raspbian

Tags: apt

I'm running Raspbian inside QEMU, and I'm getting an error when I try to run `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
dpkg: error: fgets gave an empty string from `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File'
```

Google finds almost no results for this error, and the few proposed solutions I've found haven't worked.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Is it possibly caused by low memory? QEMU is limited to only 256MB of ram.

Edit: I'm running the most recent [Jessie Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is anything in File?

Comment: @KennethSpear, Yes...although seeing as how it's presumably auto-generated by something, I don't see how I can interpret the results.

Comment: What version of Raspbian are you running?

Comment: have you tried sudo apt-get clean ?