# apt upgrade fails on fresh image

Tags: apt, pi-b

I flashed the latest version of raspbian-lite to an SD card and booted my Model B from it. I changed the hostname and other config settings in `raspi-config`, then reboted and tried to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` which failed:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error: fgets gave an empty string from '/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I noticed [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/45719/17926), which instructed me to run `sudo apt-get clean` to resolve the issue, but the problem still persists. What can I do to make aptitude function properly?

Comment: since you've only just flashed it - try starting from the beginning again - perhaps something went wrong with the flashing, or even the download! first though, what are the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File`

Comment: Flash the image and first do nothing else then `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`, reboot. With *Raspbian Stretch 2018-06-27* you will have a kernel and firmware update then.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that now, @Ingo

Comment: Nope, same error, @Ingo